# Regex for matching one occurence

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex which should check for a character and should be the only occurrence. for ex , To check for 1 occurrence of '@' I came up with `@{1}`

Although i have specified that @ should occur only one time, It matches for one or more occurrences. Whats wrong with this regex?

Comment: What's your regex flavour?

Answer (score 3):

That regex of yours checks only for 1 `@` in a row. If you want to make sure there are no other `@` in the same string, you could perhaps use negated classes and anchors:

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*$
```

(assuming that multiline flag is off, otherwise, you would use `\A` and `\z` for the beginning and end of line anchors respectively).

Point to note: `{1}` is redundant since `@` is equivalent to `@{1}`

Comment: It should be noted that `@{1}` is the same as `@`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Was typing just that :)

Answer (score 1):

To match only one, use a negative look ahead for two:

```
^(?!.*@.*@).*@.*$
```